# Combining two unrelated SELECT-s with different ORDER-s into one result

Tags: mysql, sql

**TL;DR:** How to combine two *differently ordered* `SELECT`s from *unrelated* tables into one result?

---

Let's say I have 2 non-related tables - **cats** and **games**.

Table "cats":

```
+----+----------------+-----+
| id |      name      | age |
+----+----------------+-----+
|  1 | Balthazar      |   3 |
|  2 | Milkman        |   7 |
|  3 | The Dark Angel |   4 |
+----+----------------+-----+
```

Table "games"

```
+----+----------+-------+
| id |   name   | plays |
+----+----------+-------+
|  1 | Snake    |    18 |
|  2 | Lemmings |   234 |
|  3 | Ludo     |    33 |
+----+----------+-------+
```

For each of the tables respecitively I need a `SELECT` to order them, and get different columns:

```
SELECT age FROM `cats` ORDER BY age DESC;
```

and

```
SELECT plays FROM `games` ORDER BY plays DESC;
```

Thing is I want to get both results **using one query**, instead of two. The expected result:

```
+-----+-------+
| age | plays |
+-----+-------+
|   7 |   234 |
|   4 |    33 |
|   3 |    18 |
+-----+-------+
```

No point for a `JOIN` as the tables share no relation. I was thinking of using `UNION` but I can't figure out how to handle the fact that both queries:

1. select different columns
2. order the result by different columns

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: You can dinamically add row number to each query, with variables. But why you even need it?

Comment: Even though you say the tables are not related, the desired result asserts that - at least to my eye. So, you should rather relate the two tables to each other using a column and a foreign key, because this is way easier to do in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @vp_arth Obviously, the real case is more complicated than what I posted. Basically, I have 3 unrelated content tables and I need to get "Top 10" from each of them, based on different criteria. I have thousands of entries, so I don't want to make 3 separate queries for each table.

Comment: I believe, separate queries will be much better in your case..

Comment: @vp_arth If I there's a way to decrease the number of requests from 3 to 1, with no substential change in execution time, I will always go for it :)

Answer (score 3):

One method is to calculate a row number and then join on that value:

```
select rn, max(age) as age, max(plays) as plays
from ((select c.age, NULL as plays, (@rnc := @rnc + 1) as rn
       from cats c cross join (select @rnc := 0) params
      ) union all
      (select NULL as age, g.plays, (@rng := @rng + 1) as rn
       from games g cross join (select @rng := 0) params
      )
     ) cg
group by rn;
```

Comment: I was just to forge the exact same query but you were faster... +1!

Answer (score 0):

```
select age,plays from cats inner join games on cats.id=games.id
```